# Slow extraction of data with the Bloomberg API (Matlab Datafeed Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, bloomberg, toolbox, datafeed

I am using the Datafeed Toolbox to extract data from Bloomberg. In particular I use the [functions](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/blp.history.html):

```
d = history(c,s,f,fromdate,todate)
```

I found however that the data extraction is quite slow.

E.g. for a list of 248 tickers, and for the field PX_LAST within period 1/1/2016 - 2/28/2018, it takes up to 2-3 minutes to extract the data.

Is this an issue with my Matlab or is there a way to optimize this number?

Comment: Does that require an active internet connection?

Comment: Yes, but it is not the internet. I have > 800mb/s download.

Comment: 903.01 Mbps download and 485.44 Mbps upload as given by Speedtest.net

Comment: You can try vectorising the code of the `history` function or try mex-ing it.

Comment: Just because you have gigabit download, does not mean the server you're connecting to is streaming data at that speed. There can be bottlenecks at any point in the transmission.